# How to convert first index of each array in my Array of array from string to int?

Tags: javascript

Initial :

```
var a = [["1","John"] , ["2","Alex"]]
```

Expected :

```
var a = [[1,"John"] , [2,"Alex"]]
```

Appreciate advise on how to convert the array.

Comment: Please provide your tried code also !!

Comment: Is expected [2,"Alex"] or [3,"Alex"]?

Comment: `parseInt`/`parseFloat` or `unary +` - these are three ways your code can use to convert a String to a Number

Comment: You mean `var a = [["1","John"],["3","Alex"]]`?

Comment: Hi. I already correct the number.

Comment: `["1","John"]["3","Alex"]` evaluates to `["1", "John"]["Alex"]`; as `["1", "John"]` has no attribute `Alex`, the variable `a` contains `[undefined]`. There is nothing to convert.

Comment: With [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you can do `var b = a.map(([k,v]) => ([+k,v]));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the forEach method and use parseInt to turn the index you want into an integer. Dont forget your comma to separate the index of the outter array

```
var a = [["1","John"], ["3","Alex"]];

a.forEach((innerArray)=> innerArray[0] = +innerArray[0]);

console.log(a)
```

Comment: You can also use `innerArray[0] = +innerArray[0];`

Comment: Thanks Matt & Samuel it works. I corrected the question by adding "," between array.

Comment: @Samuel Thats really cool, I didnt know that. This method even works to convert string to floats :) . lf you want to check the value of the index of the inner arrays. you can console.log(typeof(a[0][0]));

Comment: why would you accept this answer, since this changes `a`, but you want a new var `b` with the new array according to your question?

Answer (score 1):

[**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and coercing the first index to integer of nested array could be converted to your expected one.

```js
var a = [["1","John"],["2","Alex"]]
    .map(item => [+item[0], item[1]])

console.log(a);
```

**Note**: Here `+` is coercing the string to integer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), together with the [Number() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Convert_numeric_strings_and_null_to_numbers), to carry out the type conversion.

```js
const a = [['1', 'John'], ['2','Alex']];
const result = a.map(item => [Number(item[0]), item[1]]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parseInt() for each string that needs to be converted to integer.